# How do I find the program with the current focus?

Tags: c++, windows, focus

How can I know which process has the current focus?

*Edit: Windows OS, anywhere from XP to 7*

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to solve, where you think getting the program with the current focus will help?

Comment: @Raymond Chen, I would like to prototype a system that will log which window is currently open, from there determine which program is actually running (ie. Spotify) once that information is known trap/log keyboard input and perform an action (ie, keep a log of the songs searched). Thanks for the edit BTW.

Comment: So you want to make a keylogger that can target any process ;-)

Comment: In which case getting the focus window is the wrong question. You really want to log input, regardless of whether the input target is focus or not. (It can be non-focused due to asynchronous input.) But even then, you're logging at too low a level, because you will have to decode shift states, IMEs, handwriting recognition, etc. Instead, use the accessibility interfaces to obtain the text from the input box. Note of course that you will need a custom version for each target application, since Spotify and iTunes have different input models.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Call [`GetForegroundWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633505.aspx) to get the handle of the focused window, and then call [`GetWindowThreadProcessId`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633522.aspx) to get the ID of the process that created that window. What you do with that ID is up to you.

Comment: You're right. This is the API I meant to suggest .. deleting my answer and +1

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`EnumProcesses`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682629%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the list of running processes.

After you retrieve the handles, check out [`GetProcessInformation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh448381%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), there might be something there that can help you.

Answer (score 1):

the  first steps are winapi function EnumProcesses (and maybe OpenProcess)