# vb.net sendkeys to specific active application

Tags: vb.net, sendkeys

i already done on making some sendkeys application to help me make my life easier, but im annoy to it when i switch windows and i forgot to switch off the sendskeys, like for example, my application will send "123123" to the notepad (current active application) until i stop it, so when i switch to msword it will not work, then if i switch back again to notepad it will sendkeys again, is that possible? life if there is some argument like

```
If activeWindows = notepad.exe then
    do this
Else
    do nothing
End If
```

it's just an idea but i dont know how to make something like that in vb.net, and i want to use .exe instead of the title of application cause i think it's much fitting for what im doing.

thx in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `GetForegroundWindow` and `GetWindowThreadProcessId` APIs to do this for you.  Here is a quick example:

```
''' <summary>The GetForegroundWindow function returns a handle to the foreground window.</summary>
''' <returns>The return value is a handle to the foreground window. The foreground window can be NULL in certain circumstances, such as when a window is losing activation. </returns>
<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
Private Shared Function GetForegroundWindow() As IntPtr
End Function

<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
Private Shared Function GetWindowThreadProcessId(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, _
                      ByRef lpdwProcessId As Integer) As Integer
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Task.Run(AddressOf KeySender)

End Sub

Private Sub KeySender()
    While (True)

        Dim fgWin = GetForegroundWindow()
        Dim fgPid As New Integer()
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(fgWin, fgPid)

        Dim proc = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessById(fgPid)
        Console.WriteLine(proc.ProcessName)

        If (proc.ProcessName = "notepad") Then
            SendKeys.SendWait("A")
        End If


        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)

    End While
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should work, good idea. What I did so far was to read the numLock key. As long as it is on, the timer with sendkeys is firing. As soon as turned off, the timer will be stopped as well. But adding a check for the current focus would be a nice addition.

What methods to use, please check this, I think it fits [How do I find the program with the current focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8402237/how-do-i-find-the-program-with-the-current-focus)