# How do I find the program with current focus on macos?

Tags: c++, macos, macos-sierra, objective-c++

Is there API function call that returns an identifier to find out which program has current focus.

I am looking for an answer to this question but in regards to MacOS
[How do I find the program with the current focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8402237/how-do-i-find-the-program-with-the-current-focus)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either [frontmostApplication](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsworkspace/1532097-frontmostapplication) or [menuBarOwningApplication](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsworkspace/1525848-menubarowningapplication), depending on what exactly you mean by "focus".